# AS3: Error 1009:

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, null, movieclip

In a little game I have to make for college I render a menu at runtime, using movieclips i made of buttons i drawed in illustrator. I imported the illustrator file in flash professional like I always do, and made a AS linkage like I do with my other movieclips that run fine. But when I try to render these buttons I get a error 1009, a null reference. I use AS3 by the way.

```
private function initMenuComponents():void{
        var btnPlay:MovieClip = new Play();
        var btnOptions:MovieClip = new Options();
        var btnLikeOnFacebook:MovieClip = new LikeOnFacebook();
        var btnShareOnFacebook:MovieClip = new ShareOnFacebook();

        btnPlay.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (btnPlay.width / 2);
        btnOptions.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (btnOptions.width / 2);
        btnLikeOnFacebook.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (btnLikeOnFacebook.width / 2);
        btnShareOnFacebook.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (btnShareOnFacebook.width / 2);

        btnPlay.y = 100;
        btnOptions.y = 150;
        btnLikeOnFacebook.y = 200;
        btnShareOnFacebook.y = 250;

        stage.addChild(btnPlay);
        stage.addChild(btnOptions);
        stage.addChild(btnLikeOnFacebook);
        stage.addChild(btnShareOnFacebook);
    }
```

Comment: Indicate the line throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not properly linking the files in the IDE. The error you're seeing stems from this issue. I would comment out almost all of your code, and test to find exactly where the error is.

```
var btnPlay:MovieClip = new Play();
//var btnOptions:MovieClip = new Options();
//var btnLikeOnFacebook:MovieClip = new LikeOnFacebook();
//var btnShareOnFacebook:MovieClip = new ShareOnFacebook();
```

Comment: now I tried to tick on the checkbox that says 'Export in Frame 1', I keep getting the error, but instead of crashing my flash player shows three black points on white screen.

Comment: looks like none of the movieclips work anymore. I imported new illustrator files and now the library in flash professional and as3 don't communicate well anymore.

Comment: That seems to be your problem them. I've often had issues importing illutstrator files into Flash... It can be glitchey.