# AS3: Error 1009: Null reference

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, null

I am making a game in ActionScript 3. I have a Menu Class with a method that renders a Menu.
I make an instance of Menu in my Main class, and then call the method. When I debug the application I get a null reference error. This is the code of the menu class:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

import menucomponents.*;

public class Menu extends MovieClip
{
    public function Menu()
    {
        super();
    }

    public function initMenuComponents():void{
        var arrMenuButtons:Array = new Array();

        var btnPlay:MovieClip = new Play();
        var btnOptions:MovieClip = new Options();
        var btnLikeOnFacebbook:MovieClip = new LikeOnFacebook();
        var btnShareOnFacebook:MovieClip = new ShareOnFacebook()

        arrMenuButtons.push(btnPlay);
        arrMenuButtons.push(btnOptions);
        arrMenuButtons.push(btnLikeOnFacebbook);
        arrMenuButtons.push(btnShareOnFacebook);

        var i:int = 0;

        for each(var item in arrMenuButtons){
            item.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (item.width / 2);
            item.y = 100 + i*50;
            item.buttonMode = true;

            i++;
        }
}
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't you [just ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363504/as3-error-1009)?

Comment: use the debugger to see what's going on, and if you don't have a debugger handy, you can try to at least keep a log

Comment: @SamIam I get the error at the line where I try to add an item to the stage. Does that mean the stage is null or my items are null? Sorry if this is a dumb question, i never learned debugging properly at my college.

Comment: @SylvainVansteelandt and what line is that?

Comment: @SamIam I'm sorry, after posting this I tried to add in the beginning of my for each a statement: stage.addChild(item);
But the problem remains, it's always the first line of the for each loop.

Comment: I don't see where `stage` is declared, let-alone initialized, but i don't see any specific reason why `item` would throw the null exception error, so i'd probably assume the problem is with `stage`

Comment: @SamIam but stage is normally automaticly added, it's a flash professional project, you can't even instanciate stage i just tried it...

Comment: when is the `initMenuComponents()` called?  Most likely you're calling that function before the instance of your posted class (`Menu`) has been added to the stage.

Comment: @SamIam

I mean no. First added to stage. Then method called.

package
{
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.display.Stage;
 
 public class Main extends MovieClip
 {
  public function Main()
  {
   super();
   
   
   var menu:Menu = new Menu();
   
   stage.addChild(menu);
   
   menu.initMenuComponents();
  
 }
 
  
  
}
}

Comment: @SylvainVansteelandt i dont know what is causing the error offhand

Comment: @SylvainVansteelandt - update your question with the code instead of putting it in comments (as it's hard to read).

Comment: In your main class constructor (`public function Main()`), move out the line: `menu.initMenyComponents();` and replace it with:  `this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addedToStage);` then create the addedToStage function and call the `menu.initMenuComponents();` there. this will ensure that stage is ready before that method runs.

Comment: This needs to be closed/deleted. Per OPs commends here and in the answer by LondonDurgs, the problem seems to be very localized and it does not help to the community anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely that stage is not populated yet when your for loop runs.   Try the following:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip { 
    public function Main() { 
        super(); 
        var menu:Menu = new Menu(); 

        //it's good practice - as sometimes stage actually isn't populated yet when your main constructor runs - to check, though in FlashPro i've never actually encountered this (flex/flashBuilder I have)
        if(stage){
            addedToStage(null);
        }else{
            //stage isn't ready, lets wait until it is
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addedToStage);
        }
    } 

    private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
        menu.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,menuAdded); //this will ensure that stage is available in the menu instance when menuAdded is called.
        stage.addChild(menu); 
    }

    private function menuAdded(e:Event):void {
        menu.initMenuComponents(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried that, found this on a other website, didn't work. I finally fixed the problem.
Found a wicked fix at a site an magically it worked. Save file as AS2, then back as AS3. Worked.

Comment: Your issue wasn't a programming issue then but a FlashPro issue.  I'd be skeptical though of that as a real fix.